# Rails foo= vs foo_id=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If bar belongs_to foo and foo has_many bars, is there a difference between the effects of

```
my_bar.foo = my_foo
```

and

```
my_bar.foo_id = my_foo.id
```

or do both make an association between my_foo and my_bar?

I ask because I'm trying to decide whether to add the association manually when I override the setter for Bar#foo_id=(input).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question contains a slight inaccuracy, in that **neither** of these **create** an association: they set the association up ("build" it, if you like), but it won't be created, ie saved into the database, until `my_bar` is **saved**.

Both of these should set the proxy for each other:  if you say `my_bar.foo_id = 4`, then `my_bar.foo` should return the foo with id 4, even **before** it's saved, and vice versa.

If you are going to override the setter for `Bar#foo_id` (by convention, when describing methods, the hash denotes an instance method rather than a class method), you could get yourself into trouble if you don't replicate the natural behaviour of Rails.  Tread carefully.

Comment: I've used "create" too loosely, not in the formal sense. I'll update my question. Thanks for your response. This is just what I needed to know.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is that bar_id can not be filled in until the Bar record has been saved (when the id attribute is assigned). You can build a Bar object in memory and associate it with a bar (the `foo =` part) before saving either record. Usually, when you save the Bar, the foo will also be validated and saved.

- foo_id is the attribute which will be saved to the database, which will refere to a record in the FOOS table.
- foo is an instantiated ActiveRecord object which is stored as an attribute against of the bar object.

As a rule, if you are associating a new Bar with an existing foo, I would set the foo_id. If you are creating them at the same time, I would set the foo.

*Edit:* Having seen the last part of your question. If you override the setter to add functionality, I would start by calling `super(value)` to get all the existing functionality from ActiveRecord. E.g.

```
def foo_id=(value)
  super(value)
  @foo_id = value
  do_other_thing
end
```

I would recommend overriding this method in a way which removes this functionality.